# mark jenkins build failure based on the jar exception

Tags: jenkins

need to mark the build failure when java terminates by System.exit(1)

I am calling one jar from the Jenkins job configuration, and I need to mark build failure when java terminates abnormally

Comment: How do you start java (what build step)?

Comment: calling Jar from the shell script (build) using java - jar @R.Oosterholt